# 'vector' in namespace 'std' does not name a type

Tags: c++, std, stdvector

I am developing a C++ application using CodeBlocks 10.05 on Debian 7.0.0.

For some reason, the following code

```
#include <iostream>

std::vector< int > delaunayDiv(const std::vector< int <T> > & vP, cv::Rect boundRect,
    std::vector<int>& triangles, int& numTriangles, bool lookRight);
```

returns the following error

```
error: 'vector' in namespace 'std' does not name a type
```

Answer (score 168, accepted):

You should include the `vector` header:

```
#include <vector>
```

Comment: I am getting 'vector' file not found, can you please help out

Answer (score 0):

`#include <vector>` does not worked when I use Clang, I do not really know if it is a difference in C++ versions or libraries.

`#include <set>` does the trick.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](http://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/15537456)

Comment: sorry I forgot the to mark the code as code and the answer made no sense. Edited to correct it